# Unlimited window's height for Windows 7 with autohotkey

Tags: windows, autohotkey

I currently using this code:

```
!E::WinMove,A,,0,0,1920,1080
```

My current screen resolution is 1920x1080, and this script works just fine. 
 But with this script it won't:

```
!E::WinMove,A,,0,0,1920,3000
```

The last argument - the Height of the window, if it's greater than my screen resolution's height, it won't work at all. 
 
  Is there a way to work this out with autohotkey or changing any default windows's settings? Thank you very much.

Comment: there used to be a windows option in the task bar, determining whether you can move windows out of the desktops viewport. maybe that can help?

Comment: nope, I can move the window out of the screen but extend it's size greater than the screen's resolution is impossible :(

Comment: Could you elaborate on why you want to extend the window size beyond the given visible dimensions? We might be missing a potential solution in lacking the bigger picture.